# The URLs on my site changed, how can I get Google to change the URLs shown in Sitelinks?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, sitelinks

I have created a **new** website to replace the old one.

The old one had structure like this ( and its *URLs* ):

```
Site name (www.site.com/index.php)
---- Home page (www.site.com/home_page.php)
---- Programmes (www.site.com/programmes.php)
---- About us (www.site.com/about_us.php)
```

When I searched on Google for my site name it displayed the results like that.

I removed the old site from the server and uploaded the new one.

Now I'm using **CMS** for the new site (*MODx*) so the structure is like this:

```
Site name (www.site.com/index.php?id=1)
---- Home page (www.site.com/index.php?id=2)
---- Programmes (www.site.com/index.php?id=3)
---- About us (www.site.com/index.php?id=4)
```

Then when I searched Google for the site name it displayed the **last pages results**.

I found that I could remove the old URLs in *webmaster tools ⇒ optimization ⇒ remove URLs* and I removed the pages.

Now when I google my site name it displays only the **index.php** ( without the sitelinks).

How can I add the new Sitelinks to the Google search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chances are you have no waited long enough for Google to index them, Google has billions of pages each day to index, they simple don't have the resources to quickly do everyone's site and depending on your original site and how often they crawled it depends on how quickly they will update with new urls, a fairly average site takes between 2-4 weeks and varies depending how many pages you have.

You can try this:

1. Check robots.txt is not blocking Google.
2. Check to ensure you do not have noindex on the pages.
3. Optional make a sitemap.
4. Wait between 2-4 weeks.

Comment: Hm, interesting. How to make robots.txt ? Just to create a simple .txt in my root ? And what code to put in? I read that robots.txt will block the google spiders. Is that true?

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a robots unless you want to block some pages from Google. You may however already have a robots file and you should check that its not blocking, simple navigate in your address bar yourdomain.com/robots.txt (if no results are returned then you don't have one and its nothing to worry about) if you do have one then you need to check whats being blocked.

Comment: It's very unlikely that your blocking these pages, how long has it been since these new pages were added to your site? I'm guessing no more than a week ;)

Comment: I don't have the _robots.txt_ in my root. It's been about 10 days. I didn't know that it takes 2-4 weeks to google spiders optimizes the web :)
But what about the noindexing and sitemaps. Is that also automated or I have to put that manually with _webmaster tools_ ?

Comment: Check the source of your pages for metaname no index, but its doubtful you have these as these are normally intended not TO INDEX... your problem is that you haven't waited long enough for the changes to reflect on Google :P

Comment: There is nothing about indexes. I hope you're right and it's just because of the waiting period. Thanks for your time :)